# Paypal rest api - what are the possible payment states?

Tags: paypal

I am trying to simulate a payment using the paypal rest api. After calling execute I get a response object with the state "approved".

Does anyone know where there is a list of the possible states the api may return?

I presume there are a few others but I can not find the documentation that covers this.

```
paypal.payment.execute(payment_id, details, function (err, payment) {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        if(payment.state === "approved"){
            done(err, payment);
        }else{
            //handle other states
            done(err, payment);
        }

    });;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE: My previous answer is obsolete.**

#### RIGHT ANSWER As of June-2018

Looks like Paypal REST API have undergone some updates, and the `state` assigned to the `Response` are just 3.

Possible values: `created`, `approved`, `failed`.

[image]

Source: [Docs: Payments API > Payment > Create payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create)

#### 2013 Answer [ OBSOLETE ]. Useful only if you are using old version of API

According to the REST API Documentation for [Create a payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-payment), the `state` assigned in the `Response` can be any one of the following.

```
created 
approved
failed
canceled
expired
```

Comment: Ah.. there it is - thakyou

Comment: When the state is approved, is it safe to ship the product ? What doe approved exactly men in this context ? Is it 100% sure that we get the money ?

Comment: @daslicht I think the `approved` state enum response would have a different meaning, depending on what you passed in for the `intent` enum in your request. From the documentation, I think if the intent you passed in is `sale`, and you received an `approved` response, that would mean the money was paid. If, on the other hand, you send in `authorize` as your intent and you received an `approved` response, then that would mean that your intent to get an authorization to capture payment later was successful.

Comment: @shiva: yeh I set the intent to sale. So it is safe to ship the product when the state is approved ? related: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/1171

Comment: @daslicht I can't speak for paypal. You did the right thing by raising that github issue. Hopefully someone from Paypal can give you more information of whether you can ship if the state is `approved` for an intent `sale`... :)

Comment: @shiva: I already opened a paypal tech support ticket and wrote in the community forum, NO ANSWER.

Comment: @shiva
Today I finally got an answer from PayPal !:

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/IPN-vs-actions-payment-execute-result/td-p/1564037

Comment: Following up on @shiva 's comment. There seems to be yet another state: completed state. This happens when you capture an authorized payment. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/authorize-and-capture-payments/#capture-an-authorized-payment

Comment: @CharmingRobot Interesting, I see the `completed` in the link you provided. However, it looks like PayPal API Docs Keeper has not update their documentation. The possible states listed in the API Reference is still only the 3 I listed in my answer.  => https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get

Comment: I certainly hope you're right. Paypal's API is the most terrible/inconsistent API i've worked with throughout my career.

Answer (score 0):

I also discovered that the 'pending' status is possible.